# Getting css styles of related element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I use `$(audio).prev().html();`, it logs:

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="background: #DDDDDD"></div>
```

---

However, when I try to get the css attributes by using:

`$(audio).prev().css("background")`

It logs `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box`

---

What am I doing wrong? How can I get/set css attributes of an element?

Related html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="background: #DDDDDD">

    </div>
</div>
<audio id="soundB">
    <source src=sounds/B.wav>
</audio>
```

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `.prev()`? does it work then? Also, you have `box` in one and `audio` in the other.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake while writing the question. fixed now. I tried removing `prev()`, but it doesn't work either. Still logging `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box`

Comment: Can you give us the actual markup showing the html in question?

Comment: Where are you storing the element in variables?

Comment: I also tried `$(audio).prev().first().css("background")` but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `.prev()` will return `previous` element and `.html()` will return `innerHTML` of the matched element.

In this case, your statement, `$(audio).prev().html();` will return `<div class="col-md-8" style="background: #DDDDDD"></div>` element but `$(audio).prev().css("background")` will return `css` property of the parent of the expected element which is `<div class="row">`. As this element has no background style set, it is returning `rgb(0, 0, 0)`

Try this: `$(audio).prev().find('div').css("background")`

Also note: *Colors are always returned as rgb*

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving you the full style for the background of the element, not just the color that was specified. Try using "background-color" instead.